# Select always return 1 after create socket and FD_SET in linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Today I was creating a sample code socket in Linux (Debian). But it run incorrectly, after `FD_ZERO` and `FD_SET`. `select` will return 1 before time out (my expectation is that select would return 0 ) but i had not taken action with the socket. Here is my code. Could someone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(void)
{
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int sockfd, retval;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   /* Watch sockfd to see when it has input. */
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &rfds);

   /* Wait up to five seconds. */
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

   retval = select(FD_SETSIZE, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    /* Don't rely on the value of tv now! */

   if (retval == -1)
        perror("select()");
    else if (retval)
        printf("Data is available now.\n");
        /* FD_ISSET(sockfd, &rfds) will be true. */
    else
        printf("No data within five seconds.\n");

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: why do you watch file descriptor 0 in FD_SET? This is stdin. You probably tried to watch sockfd instead?

Comment: No, i watch sockfd, but it always return 1. I don't understand for this

Comment: No, you are watching FD zero, because of `FD_SET(0, &rfds)`. And you haven't either connected the socket or set it to listening. Your code doesn't make sense and neither does your question.

Comment: Sorry, i change to FD_SET with sockfd but it have the same problem

Comment: That's because calling `select()` on a socket which is neither listening nor connected still doesn't make sense. This is not real code that would ever be deployed. and it doesn't present a real problem to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is the `FD_SET`. The first parameter should be the file descriptor of the socket:

```
FD_SET( sockfd, &rfds );
```

There is also a problem in the `select` call. The first parameter must be greater than the max descriptor. From the man page for `select`:

> (Example: If you have set two file descriptors `4` and `17`, nfds
>   should  not be `2`,
>   but rather `17 + 1`, i.e. `18`.)

So the `select` call should be:

```
select( sockfd+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv );
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edit the post. I try with select FD_SETSIZE, the problem is no change? You have any ideal? Could you try this source in linux?

Comment: I have fix two things you said, but the problem has not be slove